# A computed observable as a member of observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Sorry I am new to Knockout. I'm trying to put a compute observable as a member on an observableArray. 
Something like this:

```
var viewModel = {
       data: ko.observableArray([
            [a, b, ko.computed(function () {return (a+b);})],
            [c, d, ko.computed(function () { return (c + d); })],
        ]),
    };
```

The code is not grammatically correct and I just tried to present my idea. In the code above I want the 3rd member of any array do some calculation and return the result.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the question? The code appears to work as is:
http://jsfiddle.net/qvDJ6/1/

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely right. this works if we define a variable for each member of array but I want just give the array direct numbers and have access to these member in the computed members. Something like here [http://jsfiddle.net/qvDJ6/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/qvDJ6/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to your response I made a new snippet.

```
 var viewModel = {
    data: ko.observableArray([
        [10, 20],
        [60, 40]
    ])
};
var ar = viewModel.data();
for (var index = 0; index < ar.length; index++) {
    var item = ar[index];
    item[0] = ko.observable(item[0]);
    item[1] = ko.observable(item[1]);        
    item[2] = ko.computed(function () {
       return  item[0]() + item[1]();
    });
}


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**[See the new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvDJ6/8/)**

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Damien , This works but pls check my comment on the previous post. That is my requirement.

Comment: I don't see what you are looking for? Please give the form of the input data.
Because if you write that new Item(10, 20) it works.

Comment: Actually I have an Excel like form. most of the fields are simple input field and some of them are calculational fields. for example a field might be the sum of three other fields. I want just have one observableArray and bind it to my elements. In my example here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qvDJ6/4/) I am trying to have access to the 1st and 2nd member and after some calculation return the result as a 3rd member. That's the exactly thing I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks man! this works. I changed it to this  (http://jsfiddle.net/qvDJ6/12) to get rid of declaring local variables.